# Javascript iterate through json object with objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have a special case with my json string and I don't know how to get all the information i need. This is the string reformatted:

```
        {  
           "0":{  
              "-1":"",
              "0":"VOR_CVR",
              "1":"VOR_CVR2",
              "2":"VOR_CVR3",
              "3":"VOR_CVR4",
              "4":"VOR_CVR5"
           },
           "1":{  
              "-1":"",
              "0":"VOR_RMV",
              "1":"VOR_FND",
              "2":"VOR_FND2",
              "3":"FAGGIO3_MGUARD1",
              "4":"VOR_FND3",
              "5":"VOR_FND4"
           }
}
```

I need to get the outer 0 and 1 and the inner numbers (without the string).
This is my code:

```
var mods = JSON.parse(string); //contains the json string
for (var key in mods) {
    for (var key2 in mods[key]) {
            console.log(key);
            console.log(key2);
    }
}
```

```js
var string = `{  
               "0":{  
                  "-1":"",
                  "0":"VOR_CVR",
                  "1":"VOR_CVR2",
                  "2":"VOR_CVR3",
                  "3":"VOR_CVR4",
                  "4":"VOR_CVR5"
               },
               "1":{  
                  "-1":"",
                  "0":"VOR_RMV",
                  "1":"VOR_FND",
                  "2":"VOR_FND2",
                  "3":"FAGGIO3_MGUARD1",
                  "4":"VOR_FND3",
                  "5":"VOR_FND4"
               }
    }`
var mods = JSON.parse(string); //contains the json string
for (var key in mods) {
  for (var key2 in mods[key]) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(key2);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the desired output, exactly? Post a full example of input and output

Comment: Do you want an object of indices arrays: `{ 0: [-1,0,1,2,3,4], 1:[-1,0,1,2,3,4]}` ??

Comment: Just use Object.keys()

Comment: { 0: [-1,0,1,2,3,4], 1:[-1,0,1,2,3,4]} this comes pretty near to what i want i need to get 0 and 1 and the numbers inside also note that the json may have 0,1,2,4 (skip numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Object.Keys` on `mods[key]` within the first `for` loop.

```js
var string = JSON.stringify({
 "0": {
  "-1": "",
  "0": "VOR_CVR",
  "1": "VOR_CVR2",
  "2": "VOR_CVR3",
  "3": "VOR_CVR4",
  "4": "VOR_CVR5"
 },
 "1": {
  "-1": "",
  "0": "VOR_RMV",
  "1": "VOR_FND",
  "2": "VOR_FND2",
  "3": "FAGGIO3_MGUARD1",
  "4": "VOR_FND3",
  "5": "VOR_FND4"
 }
});

var mods = JSON.parse(string); //contains the json string
for (var key in mods) {
  console.log(key);
  // console.log(mods[key]);
  var keys = Object.keys(mods[key]);
  console.log(keys);

}
```